# Работа с графическим интерфейсом других приложений

Tags: python, gui

Интересует вопрос, можно ли какими-то встроенными методами питона взаимодействовать с другими приложениями?

Например, кликнуть, ввести клавишу в определенное окно на столе,
или открыть браузер, затем кликнуть ровно посередине экрана.

Не обязательно браузер, нужно универсальное решение.

Желательно на Win7, Win10.

Comment: Это очень сильно зависит от самого GUI (менеджера): Windows, X11, Wayland, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Именно встроенными нет, но есть модуль `pyautogui` и куча других.